# Hypothesis testing for a known parameter value vs. for an estimated parameter value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cointegration, chow-test

I will motivate this question with 2 examples:

1. Cointegration coefficient known vs. unknown

The expectations theory of the term structure of interest rates establishes that the cointegration coefficient between the 10-year interest rate (Y<sub>t</sub>) and the 3-month interest rate (X<sub>t</sub>) must be 1. Therefore, to test whether these two interest rates are cointegrated using the Engle-Granger method, we can test whether the series Z<sub>t</sub> is stationary, where Z<sub>t</sub>=Y<sub>t</sub>-1*X<sub>t</sub>. In so doing, we will use one set of critical values to conduct the hypothesis test (the Dickey Fuller critical values).

If, however, we did not know the cointegration coefficient and had to determine it first by regressing Y<sub>t</sub> on X<sub>t</sub> (i.e. first step in the Engle-Granger cointegration method), we would have to use a different set of critical values (the Engle-Granger Dickey Fuller critical values) in conducting the hypothesis test that the two series are cointegrated, with the cointegration coefficient equal to the value we estimated. **Why? What exactly is different about hypothesis testing on a known/assumed parameter value vs. hypothesis testing on estimated parameter value?** To be more specific, suppose that we've estimated the cointegration coefficient and it is equal to 1. In testing the hypothesis that the two series are cointegrated with a cointegration coefficient equal to 1, we would use different critical values depending on whether the cointegration coefficient is known/assumed to be equal to 1 (Dickey Fuller critical values) or estimated to be equal to 1 (Engle-Granger Dickey Fuller critical values). **Why would these two tests differ? How exactly is the additional uncertainty arising from the fact that the cointegration coefficient was estimated (vs. known) reflected in the Engle-Granger Dickey Fuller critical values (vs. Dickey Fuller critical values)?**

2. Date of break in time series known vs. unknown

To determine whether a series is produced by a non-stationary process due to a break in the process, we can either know the break date or not know it and need to determine it. In the first case, if we know the break date, we can use the Chow test to test whether the F-statistic corresponding to the hypothesis that the break date dummy variable, as well as the break date dummy interacted with all relevant regressors are all zero. In conducting this test, a particular set of critical values will be used.

If, however, we did not know the break date, we would have to determine it first. We could estimate it by testing (Chow test) for breaks at every possible date between the first date and the last date in our dataset. We could select the date with the largest F-statistic as the break date. I've just described the QLR test. It is identical to the Chow test, except that the break date is determined rather than known and hence as Stock and Watson write "Because the QLR statistic is the largest of many F-statistics, its distribution is not the same as an individual F-statistic". **Why? Why is the distribution of the QLR statistic different from that of the Chow statistic?** **How is the additional uncertainty arising from the fact that the break date was determined/estimated (vs. known) reflected in the QLR statistic (vs. Chow statistic)?** The only difference is that in the QLR test we determined the break vs knew/hypothesized it in the Chow test.

I would be happy with a technical answer and thrilled with a technical + intuitive explanation.

Comment: You could highlight your questions (make them boldface or something) to allow anyone to see them immediately. This might be a matter of taste, of course.

Comment: I focused on the bold questions and was brought up short: what exactly would you mean by "hypothesis testing on an estimated parameter value"?  This makes no sense, because by definition all hypotheses *stipulate* parameters or sets of them: there's no estimation involved in the formulation of a hypothesis. You seem to be asking a heavily disguised version of "what's the difference between a two-sample test and a one-sample test?"  Would that be a fair interpretation?

Comment: @whuber: I am afraid you're mistaken. Please read the entire post or look up Dickey-Fuller vs. Engle-Granger Dickey-Fuller test or Chow Test vs. QLR test. In both pairs, the latter is a hypothesis test employing an estimated parameter value, whereas the former a test employing a known/assumed parameter value.

Comment: It's not a matter of "employing," because *of course* any statistical test involves a test statistic and such a statistic usually is (or can be considered to be) an estimate.  Therefore you aren't making a meaningful distinction.  I'm asking you to clarify your meaning.

Comment: Somebody who reads the entire post and not just the bold part will find the meaning of "hypothesis testing on an estimated parameter value" to be crystal clear. To say the above sentence makes no sense to you because you read the bold parts only, is not reason enough to make any edits, certainly no meaningful edits.